# Possible to get the count for the last command executed in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I am writing a script where I would like to spit out a bunch of records and then display the count as the last line.  This is what I have so far:

```
Get-Whatever -Department $Deparment
Write-Host (Get-Whatever -Department $Deparment).Count " records found"
```

But i'm curious if there is a way to do it without executing it twice.  I thought that I had read you could use `$$` somewhere but this isn't working.  Is there a better way to do this, or do I just have to run it twice?

My Desired output would look something like this:

```
Name
-------
Abe
Joe
Bill

3 records found
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you simply assign the result to a variable?

```
$d = @(Get-Whatever -dep $department); $d
Write-Host $d.Count records found
```

Note the `@(..)`. It ensures that even when `Get-Whatever` doesn't return anything, `$d` will be empty array.

Other way is e.g. `Tee-Object`. However, it somewhat "magically" creates variables, so it is not as readable as the first approach:

```
Get-ChildItem | Tee-Object -var items
Write-Host $items.Count items found
```

As for `Tee-Object` (from documentation, try `help tee-object -online`):

> The Tee-Object cmdlet sends the output
>   of a command in two directions (like
>   the letter "T"). It stores the output
>   in a file or variable and also sends
>   it down the pipeline. If Tee-Object is
>   the last command in the pipeline, the
>   command output is displayed in the
>   console.

Comment: Perfect! Does this execute the command twice or is PowerShell smart enough to reuse the results?

Comment: Edited the answer with a documentation paragraph. PowerShell is smart enough to do it only once.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
$Result = Get-Whatever -Department $Deparment
$Result; write-host "$($Result.count) records found"
```